# Error Code : 1324 Undefined CURSOR

Tags: mysql

I just started learning MySQL and am having trouble compiling a procedure.
It's giving me an error undefined cursor. I looked up a few examples on this forum and corrected my code but it still throws the same error.

```
DELIMITER $  
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROC()  
BLOCK1: BEGIN  
DECLARE LOOP1_DONE BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;  
DECLARE VAR_TKR VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 0;  
DECLARE TKR_VALUE VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 0;  
-- OTHER VARIABLE DECLARATIONS   
DECLARE CUR1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT TKR FROM STG_TBL;  
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET LOOP1_DONE = TRUE;  
-- SET VARIABLE VALUES  
OPEN CUR1;  
CUR1_LOOP: LOOP  
FETCH CUR1 INTO VAR_TKR;  
IF LOOP1_DONE THEN  
CLOSE CUR1;  
LEAVE CUR1_LOOP;  
END IF;  
-- OTHER SELECT STATEMENTS AND CALCULATIONS   
BLOCK2: BEGIN  
DECLARE LOOP2_DONE BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;  
DECLARE CUR1_DATA CURSOR FOR  
SELECT TKR_VALUE  
FROM STG_VALUE_TBL   
WHERE TKR = VAR_TKR  
ORDER BY TKR_DATE;  
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET LOOP2_DONE = TRUE;  
OPEN CUR1_DATA;  
-- SET VARIABLE VALUES  
CUR1_DATA_LOOP: LOOP  
FETCH CUR1_DATA INTO TKR_VALUE;  
IF LOOP2_DONE THEN  
CLOSE CUR1_DATA;  
LEAVE CUR1_DATA_LOOP;  
END IF;  
-- OTHER SELECT STATEMENTS AND CALCULATIONS   
END LOOP CUR1_DATA_LOOP;  
END BLOCK2;  
-- CLOSE CUR1_DATA;  <removed as not needed>
END LOOP CUR1_LOOP;  
-- CLOSE CUR1;  <removed as not needed>
END BLOCK1;  
$  
DELIMITER;
```

Please find below table and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE STG_TBL
(
ID      NUMERIC(38),
TKR     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO STG_TBL VALUES (100000,'TKR1');
INSERT INTO STG_TBL VALUES (200000,'TKR2');
INSERT INTO STG_TBL VALUES (300000,'TKR3');

COMMIT;


CREATE TABLE STG_VALUE_TBL
(
TKR_DATE    DATE,
TKR         VARCHAR(10),
TKR_VALUE   DECIMAL(20,10),
ADDED_DATE  DATE
);

INSERT INTO STG_VALUE_TBL VALUES ('01-01-2015','TKR1','10.231','01-30-2016');
INSERT INTO STG_VALUE_TBL VALUES ('01-02-2015','TKR1','18.151','01-30-2016');
INSERT INTO STG_VALUE_TBL VALUES ('01-03-2015','TKR1','22.952','01-30-2016');

COMMIT;
```

Comment: would you please include all the related tables' "create table" code?

Comment: It seems that is closing the cursors more than once.

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu - Please find attached the create table codes and sample data

Comment: @wchiquito - I have done close cursor twice for cur_data1. Once when LOOP2_DONE is set to true i.e when there is no data (so the cursor does not remain opened) and second while the program exists after completion. Isn't this correct?

Comment: Remember the scope of the objects. `CUR1_DATA` exists only within `BLOCK2`.

Comment: @Lelio Faieta - Thank you for correcting the code tags. Will follow that going forward.

Comment: @wchiquito - Thanks for the help. I removed the close cursor from the end of the block and the procedure compiled. However it is throwing a warning when I execute "1329 No Data-zero rows fetched, selected or processed". I moved the second cursor into a BEGIN END block to avoid this error and so I can declare a CONTINUE HANDLER for the second cursor. Can you please suggest if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce the warning indicated. See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1b7a/1).

Comment: Am not able to run using the Fiddle demo. Am executing the CALL from MySQL Workbench and SP executes successfully and I see data in the table. But the warning still comes up.

Comment: Fround out that this is a limitation of the MySQL version we are using. Changed the handler to below format and it worked. Thanks for your help.                                                                                                                   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    BEGIN
      SELECT 1 INTO @handler_invoked FROM (SELECT 1) AS t;
    END;